# Wierd behaviour in firebase storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a csv file in storage(firebase-admin), and In my cloud function tried to create a readable stream in it

my code is something like this.

```
const customErrObject = {any: false, messag: []};

storageFile.createReadStream().pipe(fastCsv({headers: false,})
  .on("data", async data => {
    try {
      // retrieve a user here from `firestore`
      console.log('user.empty', user.empty);
      // more codes
      // retrieve kyc data
      console.log('kyc.empty', kyc.empty);
      // create notification
    } catch (e) {
      customErrObject.any = true;
      customErrObject.message.push(e);
    }
  }
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log('customErrObject on end', customErrObject);

    if(customerErrObject.any) //return 400 with error messages

    else // return 200
  })
```

now during runtime i would expect it to follow like this

```
user.empty false
kyc.empty false
customerErrObject on end, object log here....
```

but to my surprise this showed in the logs

```
user.empty false
customerErrorObject on end, object log here...
kyc.empty false
```

it really confused me as to why it didn't follow my expected sequence.
any help would be great!